# MySQL WHERE if one is there but other is not in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get results from MySQL. but it only works if both have a valve.
Like if both WHERE is in the database it works, but if only one is in the database and the other is not it fails, this is what I have now for the code

```
        $check_ip = $_GET['ip'];
    $check_username = $_GET['username'];
    $query = "SELECT *, COUNT(ip), COUNT(username) FROM bl WHERE ip = '$check_ip' AND username = '$check_username'";
    $resultID = mysql_query($query, $linkID) or die("Data not found.");
```

Now if both IP and username are in the database it get the results, which is great, I am also wanting result if ip is there but username is not and the other way around.

It says they both not there

What is happening is when ip and username is there is says they both there.
But if ip is not and username is, it says they both not there.

I need a reply from both, so if ip is there and username is not, I need the ip data

Comment: You should initialize your variables properly to avoid warnings and problems if one of the GET variables is not set.

Comment: Both GET is this way have been set.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using `OR` Operator

```
"SELECT *, COUNT(ip), COUNT(username) FROM bl WHERE ip = '$check_ip' OR username = '$check_username'"
```

use UNION

```
SELECT *, COUNT(ip), COUNT(username) FROM bl WHERE ip = '$check_ip' 
UNION
SELECT *, COUNT(ip), COUNT(username) FROM bl WHERE username = '$check_username'"
```

Comment: I need to get results from both. For example I need to know if IP is there and username is not OR if IP is not, but username is

Comment: I have tried OR is givign me one or the other, but not both together. I need data from ip, if username is not there and if both there I need data from ip and username

Answer (score 0):

Change the `AND` to `OR` so that MySQL counts rows if one (or both) of the two conditions is true.

Answer (score 0):

As your query contains the 'AND' condition which means if both the values exists then only it will return a value. you can change the 'AND' condition to 'OR' for the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `AND` for an `OR`, please read this, it would help in the future: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/selecting-rows.html